# Trying to add class to parent of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child, parent

I'm  trying to add a class to a parent of a parent of a link, and have tried multiple methods without success.

Below are three attempts. It's supposed to add a class based to the parent's parent based on the `href` of the `a` so I have to reference it by url - I also don't know how many links there are for each href:

```
$('a[href="http://localhost/?cat=2"]').parents(":eq(1)").addClass("social-line");
$('a[href="http://localhost/?cat=3"]').parents("ul:first").addClass("knowledge-line");
$('a[href="http://localhost/?cat=4"]').closest("ul").addClass("news-line");

<ul class="post-categories">
    <li>
       <a href="http://localhost/?cat=2" rel="category">Social</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML also?

Comment: wow...  That's a bit convoluted.  Can't you find a common parent using a class or whatever and just use `var parent = $('a[href="http://localhost/?cat=4"]').closest('.myClass')`.  Then for each of your other elements use `$('ul:first', parent).addClass( ... )` and so on?

Comment: The last one looks like the best candidate.  Without the HTML, it's not clear if you are misunderstanding 'parents' and 'closest' with 'prevAll'.  Or as @JosephMarikle considers, you actually want a child of a parent.  Again, need the HTML and expected result.

Comment: are you using any loop to generate the links, or is this a static links. please provide rest of the code, need more information to help you with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in plain JS, without jQuery at all. Take a look at the below example:

```js
document.querySelector('a[href="http://localhost/?cat=2"]').parentNode.parentNode.classList.add('social-line');
```

```css
/* Just to demonstrate that it works */

.social-line:after {
  background-color: green;
  color: yellow;
  content: 'It works';
}
```

```html
<ul class="post-categories">
  <li>
    <a href="http://localhost/?cat=2" rel="category">Social</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

That's all I can help you with, given the amount of information you (didn't) provided.